# How to make "this, string format" into two tokens ("this" and "string format")

Tags: java, filereader, stringtokenizer, file-io

Im reading in a file and each line is as follows

```
Derek Simons, Jason baker
Jack Smith, Rob Thomson
```

The problem is with my tokenizer

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){ 
       System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    }
```

the output is

```
Derek Simons
 Jason baker
Jack Smith
 Rob Thomson
```

how can I get rid of that extra blank space? so that the output would be

```
Derek Simons
Jason baker
Jack Smith
Rob Thomson
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far to figure this out? Google? String javadoc maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which programming language you are using, but in many languages there is something called Trim(). so you do s.Trim();, where s is the string. That will remove all blanks

Comment: Yeah try: System.out.println(st.nextToken().trim());

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid having to trim each string manually if the input is always in the form you describe:

```
String[] tokens = line.split(",\\s*")
```

Now `tokens` will contain each name without leading spaces in the second token.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using the [.trim](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method?

> Returns a copy of the string, with
>   leading and trailing whitespace
>   omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use trim() or even just specify you StringTokenizer's delimiter as ", " (a comma followed by a space) instead of just ",".